# EF Core 6 failed to add Owned Entity when Id does not exists in Parent Entity

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have two entities

```cs
public class ParentEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OwnedEntity> OwnedEntities { get; set; }
}

public class OwnedEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Uncomment this Id to make test passed
    ////public Guid ParentEntityId { get; set; }
}
```

And simple Context

```cs
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ParentEntity> ParentEntities { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ParentEntity>()
            .OwnsMany(parent => parent.OwnedEntities);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFProviders.InMemory;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0");
    }
}
```

By default EF Core create an Foreign Key for OwnedEntity as ParentEntityId, but when I try to run a test

```cs
[TestMethod]
public async Task UpdateParentEntityShouldSucceed()
{
    var context = new MyDbContext();

    var parentEntity = new ParentEntity
    {
        Name = "Parent Entity",
        OwnedEntities = new[]
        {
            new OwnedEntity
            {
                Name = "Owned Entity 1",
            },
            new OwnedEntity
            {
                Name = "Owned Entity 2"
            }
        }
    };

    await context.AddAsync(parentEntity);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Reset context
    context = new MyDbContext();

    var parentEntityToModify = await context.ParentEntities.AsNoTracking().FirstAsync(e => e.Name == "Parent Entity");

    parentEntityToModify.Name = "Parent Entity Modified";
    parentEntityToModify.OwnedEntities.Add(new OwnedEntity
    {
        Name = "Owned Entity 3"
    });

    context.Update(parentEntityToModify);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

It failed with message

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

However uncommenting ParentEntityId fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Setting the ParentId explicitly fixed it for me.

```
var ownedEntityToAdd = new OwnedEntity
{
    Name = "Owned Entity 3",
    ParentEntityId = parentEntityToModify.Id
};
```